# What is the equivalent for, SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN (1,2,5,9) in Django

Tags: python, django

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    req = self.request.POST
    ids = req.get('ids')
    imported_data =table_import.objects.filter(id=ids)
```

in which ids has values 1,2,5,7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

note that ids i will assume is a list.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    req = self.request.POST
    ids = req.get('ids')
    imported_data =table_import.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```